# Cannot edit QTableWidgetItems

Tags: qt, qtableview, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I want to make items of QTableWidget editable for user. The following code works perfectly when it is compiled within a separate project:

```
QTableWidget *tablewidget = new QTableWidget;

// Add data
tablewidget->insertRow(0);
tablewidget->insertColumn(0);
tablewidget->insertColumn(1);

QTableWidgetItem *item;
item = new QTableWidgetItem("editable");
tablewidget->setItem(0,0,item);
```

I can double click to cell and it becomes ready to receive keys.

But when I make this code a part of my existing project (exactly this code, no difference and no connections to existing code), **double click on cell causes nothing** - cell is not editable!

This project is really big and full code review will take enormous amount of time.

My first assumption - maybe Qt allows globally set non-editable state for all instances of QTableWidget/QTableWidgetItem? Or register delegates globally?

What do you think root cause is?

Answer (score 0):

The `QTableWidget` is editable by default and have `DoubleClick` as edit trigger.

But your already existing project may have changed these properties. You can change them to default. First try setting edit trigger for the whole table:

```
tableWidget->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::DoubleClicked);
```

If it doesn't solve your problem, then try changing each item's editable property:

```
item->setFlags(item.Flags() | Qt::ItemIsEditable);
```